# Are there any other Java quines, besides the one listed on the Wikipedia page?

Tags: java, algorithm, puzzle, quine

I know that there is a program code that print itself that is `Quine code`
As the following

```
public class Quine
{
  public static void main( String[] args )
  {
    char q = 34;      // Quotation mark character
    String[] l = {    // Array of source code
    "public class Quine",
    "{",
    "  public static void main( String[] args )",
    "  {",
    "    char q = 34;      // Quotation mark character",
    "    String[] l = {    // Array of source code",
    "    ",
    "    };",
    "    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )           // Print opening code",
    "        System.out.println( l[i] );",
    "    for( int i = 0; i < l.length; i++ )    // Print string array",
    "        System.out.println( l[6] + q + l[i] + q + ',' );",
    "    for( int i = 7; i < l.length; i++ )    // Print this code",
    "        System.out.println( l[i] );",
    "  }",
    "}",
    };
    for( int i = 0; i < 6; i++ )           // Print opening code
        System.out.println( l[i] );
    for( int i = 0; i < l.length; i++ )    // Print string array
        System.out.println( l[6] + q + l[i] + q + ',' );
    for( int i = 7; i < l.length; i++ )    // Print this code
        System.out.println( l[i] );
  }
}
```

Is there another Java Program code that print itself ?

Comment: A program that prints itself is per definition a quine.

Comment: [By definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing)), a quine is a program that prints its own source code.  So the answer to your literal question is: no.

Comment: Every turing complete language has infinitely many quines

Comment: @Patashu So that ... is a Java has many quines

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Quine is,  by definition, a program whose output is itself.

So, while there are numerous possible programs that print their own source other than the one you provided, there at none that are *not* a quine.

Since Java is a Turing complete language, there are an infinite number of quines that could be written with it ([source](http://www.madore.org/~david/computers/quine.html#sec_intro)).

Comment: I think the question is: what are those *numerous possible quines* The second part of your second sentence "*there at none...*" doesn't make any sense to me